# Rails console: Unable to autoload constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, associations, autoload, rails-console

I have a Customer_ratings model that allows users to leave feedback on each other.  The web app is working properly, and feedback is collected, stored and displayed.

I wanted to go in and delete some feedback through the rails console, but when I enter `Customer_rating.all`, I get the following error:

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Customer_rating, expected /Users/myapps/app/models/customer_rating.rb to define it
```

Similarly, if I enter Customer_rating[0], I get:

```
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Customer_rating
```

I don't have this issue while accessing other tables through my console.

What could be causing the issue, and why wouldn't this error prohibit Customer_ratings from working properly through the web app?

Comment: I see couple of problems here. Lets discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: FYI all constants need to be [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) -- you should be calling `CustomerRating`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It seems like a case of messed up naming convention.

As per `Rails` naming convention, *file names* should be in `snake_case` and *class names* in `CamelCase`. In your scenario, the file name should be `customer_rating.rb` and class name should be `CustomerRating`.

After making these changes, use `CustomerRating.all`(as the updated class name is `CustomerRating`) to fetch all the customer ratings. *Do not use* `Customer_rating.all`.

Comment: CustomerRating.all vs Cutomer_rating.all was the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: I got similar error message in different case. My mistake was, I made a Typo in class name and rails was unable to find the expected class in the file. Fixed now.

Answer (score 7):

I'd also like to add a scenario of this problem that I found for future reference.

I'm running Rails 4.0 and I had this same problem but what happened was I had a model named Student inside student.rb that was contained in a folder called Student. I didn't realize it at first but the folder name was the problem. Changing the folder name to something other than a model name solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

If the naming convention is not off, like in this question, it may be an issue on initial first load if you're making a lot of requests at the same time. I experienced this with nested controllers Api::LocationsController.

I solved it by enabled eager_load in development env:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  # Enabled this to avoid crash unable to autoload controller 
  # Error happens when you start and stop server on initial requests
  # solution found via https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32082#issuecomment-367715194
  config.eager_load = true
```

I based this off of rails issues comments: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32082#issuecomment-367715194

Answer (score -4):

You just need to modify the name of the Module

For example if the link is http://sairam.esy.es/users/customer_rating then
you controller should like be

```
module Users
  class RatingController
    # ...

    def customer_rating
      # ...
    end

    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: This is not Ruby syntax